# Resize Listviewcolumns(Details

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I created so many listviews in my project, that im too lazy to add to each listview a resize event with percentages. Is there any other trick, who just scales the columns so as they are?

thx

Comment: Can you show your resize event?

Comment: I dont have one, because I have so many listviews, that im too lazy to add to everyone a resize event, which must contains the percentage. So I was asking, if there is another method.
Sorry if it was not understandable.

Comment: Saying you're lazy is not a good excuse and doesn't exactly endear someone else into helping you.  In regards to your question, are all of the columns always suppose to be the same width?  Meaning, if the listview control is 200 pixels wide and you have 4 columns, are all 4 columns suppose to be 50 pixels?

Comment: They should be scaled like they are, so if there are 4 columns and the first one is 20 px, and the three other are 60 pixel wide, they should be, if the control has the double width, 40 or 120px wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to autosize them. I can't remember exactly but it involves setting the column width to 0, -1 or -2. It's probably -1 or -2. Try that out.

Comment: Thx, it works good,but when i resize the form there is w flickering for one second

Answer (score 1):

If you handle the Resize event using the same code for each ListView, it is sufficient to create a single method and use it as event handler for each ListView. At the time the event handler code is executed, you can obtain an instane which raised the event from the sender parameter. Besides the parameter is of the Object type, it actually contains a reference to a ListView instance. So, you can cast the parameter value to the ListView type.

Comment: Year, i also thought so, but how can i obtain the initialization width, i thought i could calculate each percantage and i could resize them,btw is there any before resize event?

Answer (score 0):

This question is hard to answer because there is not enough details. If you have a list view and it is populated then you can use the following code to auto resize columns:

```
this.listControl.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
```

It works fine in my projects so you might give it a try as well.

Comment: Sounds good, but i don't know what a populated listview is.its a listview in details mode, and i entered the columns already before, i don't created any column dynamically. In which event should i use this?